# What does it mean "get the email off"?

Tags: word-usage

During watching a gameplay walkthrough of a games named "SOMA"

I came across this sentence, " I got the email off. he must have caught up by now."

What does it mean "get the email off"?

I googled it, but still I can't get it what that means.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

That means he sent it out to him and now he expects him to receive it. The email was no longer on his computer, it was off the computer.